# Copy multiple features in feature class, update field value based on number copied

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, cursor

I have created a field which will indicate the records I want to alter. What I want to do is then cycle through these records, each will contain sum values in a field.Based on the sum I want to copy the feature a certain number of times. For example if the sum is 107 I want to copy it 11 times with resulting copied features having 10 records with a sum of 10 and 1 record with the remainder of 7 in the sum field.

I'm not sure if that makes sense so I'll, I'll be starting with something like:

```
Feature SUM_FIELD
A       107
B       38
```

I would like to end with something like:

```
Feature SUMFIELD
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       10
A       7
B       10
B       10
B       10
B       8
```

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: This is an excellent use case for reading your first table using arcpy.da.SearchCursor while writing your second table using arcpy.da.InsertCursor. If you get stuck post a code snippet that works up until the point at which you are stuck.

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo, I would use MakeFeatureLayer with a definition query and GetCount to populate the field either before or while copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("new feature class", ("SHAPE@", "SUMFIELD"))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("existing feature class", ("SHAPE@", "SUM_FIELD")) as search:
    for row in search:
        geometry = row[0]
        sum = row[1]
        tens = int(sum) / 10
        ones = int(sum) % 10

            if ones == 0:
                for x in xrange(tens):
                    insert.insertRow((geometry, 10))
            else:
                for x in xrange(tens):
                    insert.insertRow((geometry, 10))
                insert.insertRow((geometry, ones))
```

As far as your question below, I would just copy the OBJECTID of the original feature and then do a join based on that field and export a new feature.

```
insert = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("new feature class", ("SHAPE@", "SUMFIELD", "OriginalOID"))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("existing feature class", ("SHAPE@", "SUM_FIELD", "OID@")) as search:
    for row in search:
        geometry = row[0]
        sum = row[1]
        tens = int(sum) / 10
        ones = int(sum) % 10
        oid = int(row[2])

            if ones == 0:
                for x in xrange(tens):
                    insert.insertRow((geometry, 10, oid))
            else:
                for x in xrange(tens):
                    insert.insertRow((geometry, 10, oid))
                insert.insertRow((geometry, ones, oid))
```

So in the new feature class you only two fields- the SUMFIELD and field called OriginalOID (short int data type).

Then join the output (OriginalOID) to the original feature class (OBJECTID) and export a new feature with the joined attributes.

You may want to post that as a separate question though.

Comment: Thanks @ian I pry won;t get to test this for a few days as other things have come up. I managed to form some ideas based on what you and the others suggested. If I get some code going I'll post it.

Comment: @standard Hey, no problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've taken a look at the above code, modified it a bit and it works great. Is there a way I can it so that it also include values from all other fields in the records? I initially tried using "*" in place of "SUMFIELD" with the insert cursor however, this creates a field match error "TypeError".

Comment: @standard I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks again, I was just working on creating an auto increment field to use as a primary key for a join. It's good to know I was at least heading in the right direction.